# How do I permanently delete fontbook from mac (Sierra OS)?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, bash, font-book

When I try to drag to trashcan, it says it's a system app that is required by os.

How do I bypass this check and remove the app?

Comment: Current answers aside... why do you think you need to?

Comment: I am extremely sick of fontbook by this point and don't even want to be reminded of its presence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are instructions for removing font book on this page

http://www.jklstudios.com/misc/osxfonts.html#fontfolderlocations

If you just want it hidden, there's always a `chflags` command to hide it. You need to bypass SIP restrictions on that folder before you can delete or change the flags to hide it, so it's not going to be quicker than removing it - just easier to undo if you find you or another program needs it at a later date.

```
ls -laO / && ls -laO /Applications | grep Font
```

The first listing shows the variety of flags *(hidden, sunlink, restricted, uchg)* and the second shows Font Book is restricted from change even by root.

https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/

Answer (score 1):

Just like the warning says, Font Book is a system app. That means it's part of the operating system. You can't delete it because it handles important functions that make your computer work. It handles all the fonts on your computer, including the one you're using to read this website. Apple has some [info on Font Book in their Mac Basics documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201749).

EDIT for the truly determined:

I see what you're saying. However, if you take a look at threads of folks removing Font Book, you'll see all on the older side. Starting with El Capitan, Apple introduced System Integrity Protection. You can disable SIP, but it can be pretty dangerous. However, Apple did make that a tiny bit easier in Sierra by no longer requiring a boot into your Recovery partition to make the change. (That should give you an indication of how strongly this is discouraged!)

[Here's a quick article](http://blog.eriknicolasgomez.com/2016/12/13/system-integrity-protection-sip-changes-in-macos-sierra-10-12-2/) describing the Terminal commands to turn off SIP in Sierra without booting into Recovery. With SIP off, you should be able to delete whatever you want, so you'll probably want to turn it back on *as soon as you're done* dumping Font Book.

Comment: Actually, it isn't necessary to make the computer work at all. The error message also occurs when you try to delete chess. Is the entirely functionality of Sierra dependent on the chess application? I think not. Fontbook is a font manager just like any other and deleting it will not delete the system fonts found in the system/font folder. I just need to know how to gain the permissions necessary to delete it. Many have claimed to have done it, but no one has provided an explanation as to how on any of the forums I went on.

Comment: You can have other font managers, but there always needs to be a fallback in case the one you prefer stops working. I have two or three font managers on my Mac. I understand that removing the manager won't remove the fonts, but it may prevent you from accessing them in some applications.

Comment: It doesn't though because many have claimed to have removed the fontbook with no issue. Take at look at this comment thread for example. The person in question is Kurt Lang: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1641835?tstart=0

Comment: This is something that has actually changed on the Mac since that discussion thread. Just added updated info about SIP to the answer if you're truly determined.

Comment: **Disabling SIP can only be done from the Recovery OS!**

Comment: just as an update: I successfully deleted fontbook and I have no issues at all. Perfectly doable process.